# Откуда оверхэд по данным при отправке PUT-запроса через $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

Код вида:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: < url > ,
  data: < data > ,
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-262143/4136510'
  },
  complete: function(headers) {
    //code
  }
});
```

где `<data>` - кусок pdf-файла размером 262144, при выполнении (отправке запроса) выдает Content-Length 388318.
Подскажите, откуда берется оверхэд.
Спасибо.

Comment: может это разные единицы измерения? Как вы узнали размер куска pdf-файла?

Comment: скорее всего проблема в том, что по http передаются печатаемые символы типа a-z, поэтому приходится непечатаемые символы отправлять закодированными, что увеличивает объем данных. Про email можно почитать [здесь](http://ask-leo.com/why_are_emailed_attachments_larger_than_the_original_file.html), но те же причины должны быть и здесь

Comment: korytoff, файл загружает через readAsBinaryString и делится на части по 262144 байт посредством slice.

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо. Проблема решена.

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.